How to run both storybook and cypress in headless mode
I am trying to use storybook and cypress for component testing with Angular framework .I am able to run test cases when storybook server and cypress are running separately but finding difficult to run both storybook and cypress in headless mode .My need is to start storybook server in headless mode or on no watch mode and run cypress test cases on stories.
I tried to add some custom commands in angular json but it didn’t work for me .I even tried to use few cli commands to run storybook in non watch mode but no help.
Please refer the below stackblitz for reference.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xc3fa?file=cypress%2Fspec.cy.ts,.storybook%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fstories%2Ftest.stories.ts,angular.json
Changes are mainly part of below folders.
.Story
src/stories
cypress
angular.json
CLI Options: https://storybook.js.org/docs/api/cli-options
Cypress gives a way to run test cases in headless mode.Could anyone please suggest if there is away to handle headless mode in storybook as well?
I have gone through documentation of Storybook to know if there is a way to handle storybook in CICD .But couldn't find more details .I have to run storybook first in non interactive mode ,Once the storybook server is up ,I have to run cypress on the target storybook server.

You can use this package Concurrently to run commands in sequence or in parallel. Then you can combine this command with Wait on package to wait for the story book to run and then start the cypress tests.
"test": "concurrently '<< story book run command here! >>' 'wait-on http://localhost:4200 && << cypress test command here! >>'" --success last

This logic will work on CICD, also you can use success flag to set which command will determine the whole process success/failure.

Hi Naren. Thanks for this answer. This works fine for me but i am facing issue while receiving exit code from the commands .
Ex:  "concurrently --kill-others 'ng run angular-app:storybook' 'wait-on http://localhost:6006 && npm run cypress:run' --success last"
this command runs fine and exits but doesnt return back any code to validate if the jobs went fine or not.Can you please suggest on how we can handle return code ?

@code_buddy You can play around with the settings of concurrently to try to fix it, but would suggest running the command using a node.js script and trying to  capture the error code, but why would you even need an error code?
